# Need to create a table to show both mean and median together

Tags: python, pandas

Calculated the mean and median of Age for different genders for a specific country using the below code

```
df= df[df['Country']== 'United States']        
mean = df.groupby(by='GenderSelect')['Age'].mean()                          
median = df.groupby(by='GenderSelect')['Age'].median() 
print(US_mean,US_mdian)
```

Output

```
GenderSelect
A different identity    31.000000
Female                  33.436620
Male                    35.649123
Name: Age, dtype: float64
```

```
GenderSelect
A different identity    31
Female                  31
Male                    33
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

How to show the output in a table displaying both mean and median in separate columns?

Comment: use `pd.concat([mean, median], axis=1)`  You might want to rename your series also, `pd.concat([mean.rename('mean'), median.rename('median')], axis=1)`

Comment: `df['mean'] = df['Age'].groupby('GenderSelect').transform(np.mean)`

Comment: Hi Scott I tried using the above code and it worked. Thank You !!  But the column title just shows Age for both the columns. I need to change the name to mean Age and median Age . Is there any way that we could do this?

Comment: Use the second code where you rename the series inside the pd.concat.

Comment: Also i have to get the same details for another country and shows it as a next item in the table. I am not sure how to do that

Comment: @Zac pandas does intrinsic data alignment, which means that it will align elements with the same row index labels and column header labels.  It does this automatically.  Order doesn't matter.

Comment: To get these summary results broken out by country, do `df.groupby('Country')...`

Answer (score 0):

You might just want something like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10*3*2).reshape((20, 5)))
df.columns = [chr(97 + x) for x in df.columns]
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: x % 3 == 0)
df.head()
```

So now we have a dataframe with 3 columns, and one of them takes on two values (True and False). We want to find the mean, median of column 'b' for each given 'a'.

```py
def foo(x):
    return {'mean': x.mean(), 'median': x.median()}
df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(foo).unstack()
```

Or if you don't have too much data (or you don't mind waiting) you can do:

```py
df.groupby('a')['b'].describe()
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.agg()` accepts a list of functions:

```
df.groupby(by='GenderSelect')['Age'].agg([pd.Series.mean, pd.Series.median])
```

Notes:

- You can use a mix of numpy, pandas and your own lambda functions, e.g. `np.mean`, `pd.Series.mean` etc.
- If you wanted to pass non-default arguments, e.g. special treatment of NAs, or custom args to `pd.Series.rank`, you'd have to define a lambda.

To get these summary results broken out by country, do `df.groupby('Country')...`